# vino-server doesn't start automatically

Tags: mate, vino

```
**Ubuntu Mate 1.8.1**
**Linux operator 3.16.0-28-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 12 17:37:40 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux**
```

How to make vino-server starting automatically before login?. It's working only when i do "/usr/lib/vino/vino-server" in terminal and only under one logged user.

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Menu** > **Preferences** > **Default App...** > **Autostart**
and add the command you need.